# javascript and c++ boolean conversions

Tags: javascript, c++

Is there a reason that the language designer made this happen?

javascript:

```
var a = 1 + (2 || 3); // ==> 3
```

c++:

```
int a = 1 + (2 || 3); // ==> 2
```

Comment: are you sure about the `c++` result?

Comment: @Jai C++ result is correct. `2 || 3` is equivalent to `(2 != 0) | (3 != 0)` (both operands are interpreted as boolean values as in `if(2)`). Would have been different if using `2 | 3`, interpreting both operands as int and resulting in 3...

Comment: Why the downvotes? I find this an interesting question, given that I can reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: Thanks guys! 
I know how the results come out though, I am just wondering why the language designer want to do this ?
They are all high-level languages. Why should have different behaviour in some common operators?
It is non-sense that I have to face this issue when porting C++ algorithm to JS …

Answer (score 3):

The Logical OR operator's behavior is different in both. This sequence will explain

JavaScript

```
1 + (2 || 3)
1 + ((2 != 0) ? 2 : 3)
1 + 2
3
```

C++

```
1 + (2 || 3)
1 + ((2 != 0) || (3 != 0))    // <-- gets reduced to boolean
1 + 1
2
```

FYI: `1 + (2 | 3)` will result to `4` in both. See for yourself.

Comment: C++: rather `(2 != 0) || (3 != 0)`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, @Aconcagua, Corrected.

Comment: @Shreevardhan `Is there a reason that the language designer made this happen?`

Answer (score 0):

In js version, `a || b` will return `a` if `a` is true value (non-zero number, object, non-empty string, and so on), otherwise return `b`. So `2 || 3` will return `2`, `a` equals `3`

In c++ version, when evaluate `a || b`, `a` will be converted to `bool` type, if `(bool)a` is `true`, then `a || b` will be `true`. The result of `2 || 3` is `bool` value `true`, when `true` is added with a `int`, `true` will always be converted to `1`, so `1 + true` equals `2`